# Prove j(E) is an integer for an elliptic curve with CM by a quadratic field of class number 1

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, complex-multiplication

If $E$ has CM by an imaginary quadratic ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $h(\mathcal{O}_K)=1$, how would we show that $j(E)$ is an integer? (or, equivalently, that $j(\frac{1+\sqrt -t}{2})\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $\bf Z$$[\frac{1+\sqrt -t}{2}]$ has class number 1)

The shortest proofs I've seen are based on using $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{C})$, for example
[image]

but I cant understand how the automorphisms of the complex numbers allow one to prove an element is algebraic. Since we're considering all of $\mathbb{C}$, why couldn't some automorphism send an algebraic number to a transcendental one? In other words, how would one even show that an algebraic number has a finite orbit under the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$? I'm able to understand the essence of the proof but the first part makes no sense to me. Is there another short proof which is more clear?

Comment: A (field) automorphism preserves $0$ and $1$, hence all positive integers, hence all integers.  So if $p(x)=0$ for some integer polynomial $p$ then $p(\sigma(x))=0$.  An automorphism can’t send algebraic numbers to transcendental ones.

Comment: @ErickWong isn't the only automorphism of C complex conjugation?

Comment: @ErickWong oh so for example for some $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{C})$, $\sigma(2^{1/3})=w*2^{1/3}$? (w is a cube root of unity) Basically the automorphism group of C is like all the elements of the galios groups of all algebraic numbers? (And more automorphisms for transcendental numbers however those are defined)

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a reasonable way to visualize automorphisms of $\mathbb C$.  Apparently the cardinality of the automorphism group is $2$ to the power of continuum, so I suspect most of the freedom is in moving transcendentals around rather than the Galois actions among the algebraics.

Comment: @ErickWong I just have one more question: is each automorphism able to change more than one element? For example, if $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{C})$ satisfied $\sigma(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$, would it be inert for all other algebraic numbers, or could it also satisfy, say, $\sigma(2^{\frac{1}{3}})=w*2^{\frac{1}{3}}$? I don't know why but I'm thinking that if it changes more than one element it wouldn't hold as an automorphism.

Comment: No, it couldn’t possibly be inert at all other algebraics, since any polynomial relations with integer coefficients must be preserved: choosing $\sigma(\sqrt2)$ limits your options for $\sigma(2^{1/4})$.  Moreover, the composition of two automorphisms is always an automorphism, so it makes no sense to say that an automorphism can only move one element (or “essentially” one) at a time.

Comment: @ErickWong you're right. Am I being dumb or is this actually a relatively complex topic? I now understand that my thinking of $\sigma$ only changing one algebraic number is flawed, couldn't it remain inert for most other algebraic numbers? For example if sigma send the root of two to its conjugate, it would have to send the 4th root of 2 to itself*i or -i, but can't it be inert on $\sqrt(3)$ (or all square roots of odd numbers)? it would still preserve the roots of its minimal polynomial and the minimal polynomial of it multiplied by the root of 2.

Comment: It's fair to say that $\operatorname{Gal}\left(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q\right)$ is a pretty complicated group that has been studied a great deal, so I wouldn't feel bad if I were you :).  Certainly if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ factors over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$, then $\sigma$ would have to send $\alpha$ to a root of a different factor.

Comment: You're right that this doesn't seem to affect $\sqrt{3}$, but it would affect higher-degree irrationals.  So my highly *uninformed* hunch would be that only a positive "proportion" of other algebraics could remain inert.  This might qualify as "most" but it wouldn't qualify as "almost all".

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ is algebraic, it is a zero of a polynomial $f$ over $\Bbb Q$.
But $\sigma$ preserves the coefficients of $f$, so $0=f(\alpha)^\sigma=f(\alpha^\sigma)$, therefore $\alpha^\sigma$ is a zero of $f$, so one of the finitely many
conjugates of $\alpha$.

If $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $\Bbb Q(\alpha)\cong\Bbb Q(X)$, the rational
function field. Then $\Bbb Q(X)$ has automorphisms sending $X$ to $X+c$
for any $c\in\Bbb Q$. So $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ has an automorphism $\sigma$ sending
$\alpha\to\alpha+c$, and a Zorn's lemma argument extends this to an automorphism
of $\Bbb C$. So $\alpha$ has infinitely many images under $\text{Aut}(\Bbb C)$.

The only other proof I know for the theorem on CM elliptic curves is the
"honest" one using the modular equation.

Comment: Okay I think I understand a bit better. If we apply this automorphism to the coefficients $g_2(\Lambda)$ and $g_3(\Lambda)$, we get two new values which can be be represented by $g_2(\Lambda')$ and $g_3(\Lambda')$ of a new lattice $\Lambda'$ we can then prove that $\Lambda'$ has CM by elements $\sigma(\alpha)$ if the original lattice has CM by $\lambda$ since $\alpha$ is imaginary quadratic, the automorphism sends it to its conjugate, so the action of the automorphism sends the endomorphism ring to itself, this shows that the endomorphism rings of $E$ and $E^\sigma$ are equal. Is this close?

Comment: There's some errors I made while typing that I can't edit for some reason, I hope you can see through it